# Async Await call sending partial object

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and following a tutorial on Youtube.  I am attempting to make an API call to return a cart object, after receiving that object I would like that object to be passed to a child component where an ID property will be pulled from the cart to generate a checkout token.  The issue is that when the API call is made to get the cart it will not consistently wait before passing the object to the child component through props.  Sometimes it's the object, sometimes just the name of the object, sometimes an empty object.  I'll write out some partial code here to demonstrate

App Component

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState();

const fetchCart = async() => {
  setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve();
}

useEffect(() => {
fetchCart();
},[]);

<routerstuff...>
  <Route Path="/checkout" element={<Checkout cart={cart} />}>
```

Checkout component

```
const Checkout = { cart } => {

const generateToken = async () => {
  commerce.checkout.generateToken(cart.id, { type = 'cart'});

useEffect(() => {
  generateToken();
}, [cart]);
```

Comment: I recommend adding some `console.log`s into your `useEffect` functions.  You'll see that the components render more often than you're expecting them to.  You'll eventually end up adding some input validation in your `generatateToken` function that checks for a valid cart before acting (e.g. `if(!cart.id) { return; }`.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, you’re right it renders more than I thought it would. Is there a way to tell the app to not pass the object as a prop until it has the full object? I suppose I could do some validation logic in the component?